# Unable to connect to local server in C# mail program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, smtp

I am unable to connect to the frontier mail server with the following code.  I get the message "Unable to connect to remote server".  I am running the program using C# on my local computer.

```
         try
          {
              MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
              SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.frontier.com");

              mail.From = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
              mail.To.Add("xxxx@frontier.com");
              mail.Subject = thistitle;
              mail.Body = thisdescription;

              System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
              attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(thisimage);
              mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

              SmtpServer.Port = 25;
              SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "xxxxxxx");
              SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

              SmtpServer.Send(mail);
              MessageBox.Show("Mail sent");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Email Error Message");
          }
```

Can anyone tell if I have the correct parameters for Frontier mail?  I know they use Yahoo but I tried that also with no success.  Isn't it possible to run a mail server from my local machine?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just try remove this code `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;`

Comment: they must response diffrent message, if response the some message that means is a same excption. can you check you internet able visit host smtp.frontier.com on port 25?

Comment: you can use `telnet` client to try, use this command` telnet -open smtp.frontier.com 25 ` if is not responsed this message like `220 relay03.roch.ny.frontiernet.net ESMTP Postfix` that means you can't visit stmp.frontier.com on port 25.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ISP block SMTP traffic? (this is often the case for non-commercial accounts).

If not... rewrite you code closer to this:

```
    try
    {
        using (var attachment = new Attachment(thisimage))
        using (var mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
            mail.To.Add("xxxx@frontier.com");
            mail.Subject = thistitle;
            mail.Body = thisdescription;
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.frontier.com"))
            {
                client.Port = 25;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "xxxxxxx");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(mail);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Mail sent");
    }
    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {
        // go read through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx
        // go read through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception(v=vs.110).aspx
    }
#if DEBUG
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Email Error Message");
    }
#endif
}
```

...and run it in a debugger and look at what the SmtpException is reporting. There are myriad reasons why you may fail a connection.

Comment: I received the following error with the above code:    message "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 199.224.64.207:25\r\n  How do I find out if my ISP blocks SMPT traffic?

Comment: I ran it again with port 587 and disabled EnableSs1 and received the message "Sender address rejected:  Access denied".

Answer (score 0):

Im unable to comment so I will type my comment as an answer. Are you able to use ImapClient instead of SmtpClient ? With Imap, you can do some authenticating processes. Could be the issue, it only looks like you are signing in. For Imap I do this:

```
 using (var clientTest = new ImapClient())
 {
    clientTest.Connect("xxxx@frontier.com");
    clientTest.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH");
    clientTest.Authenticate(eMail, pw);
    bIsConnected = clientTest.IsConnected;

     if (bIsConnected == true)
     {
        /// Insert Code here
     }
 }
```